# Empty list inside QueryDict actually is not empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, request

I have a [QueryDyct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object (request.data) in my method and want to do some modifications on it so I have copied it: `data_dict = data.copy()`. On creating an empty list in it, it creates an additional inner list:

```
data_dict['emails'] = []
data_dict['emails'].append('foo@mail.com')
data_dict['emails'].append('bar@mail.com')
```

Instead of crating an empty list and append data into it, it creates  a list of list, and appends data into inner list:

On PyCharm watch it is shown as:

[image]

Why it behaves like this?
And for the further processing it is treated (by django validator) as an email with address `['foo@mail.com', 'bar@mail.com']`, but I want to have two different emails with appended addresses.

How can I construct normal empty list in QueryDict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) is a `MultiValueDict` to begin with, as you can repeat GET-parameters. I.e. it handles its values in lists by default. Good news is that you can use its features directly to handle lists:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict

d = QueryDict(mutable=True)
d.setlist('emails', ['abc@abc.com', 'def@abc.com'])
d['emails']
# 'def@abc.com'
d.getlist('emails')
# ['abc@abc.com', 'def@abc.com']
d.appendlist('emails', 'foo@bar.baz')
d
# <QueryDict: {'emails': ['abc@abc.com', 'def@abc.com', 'foo@bar.baz']}>
d.urlencode()
# 'emails=abc%40abc.com&emails=def%40abc.com&emails=foo%40bar.baz'
```